# Show 'saved' label for 2 seconds then hide in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

What is the best way to show a `label` (containing text = saved successfully) after saving data to only be visible  (visible = true) and then disappear (become visible = false) after say 2 seconds? I have seen people use timers before but cant get them to work.

```
if (saved == true)
{
   //data saved - show label and then make visible = false
   lblsuccess.Visible = true;
   lblsuccess.Text = "Visit saved";
}
```

Comment: Do it with use of javascript.

Comment: Cant as i need it with server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this and it did the trick for me! Thanks for your answers above though

```cs
  if (saved == true)
  {
        lblsuccess.Visible = true;
        lblsuccess.Text = "Visit saved";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideLabel", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(\"document.getElementById('" + lblsuccess.ClientID + "').style.display='none'\",2000)</script>");

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Timers.Timer timer1;


timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
timer1.Enabled=false;
timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblsuccess.Visible = false;
            timer1.Enabled=false;
        }

 if (saved == true)
            {
                //data saved - show label and then make visible = false

                timer1.Enabled=true;
                lblsuccess.Visible = true;
                lblsuccess.Text = "Visit saved";
             }
```

Comment: Re-edited by a user whose edit had been rejected..I thank him. I had two semantic typos

Comment: Is this for a windows apps or asp.net? As I am getting error with ElapsedEventHandler

Comment: use Timer Control and [Timer]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Timer tick

Comment: Oh forgot to out using system.timers; at top

Answer (score 2):

**Use This one line code in CS**
Set by default label Visibility= False;

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock (this.Page, typeof (Page ), "script" , "window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('" + lblSubMsg.ClientID + "').style.display = 'none' },2000);", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (saved == true)
            {
                //data saved - show label and then make visible = false    

                lblsuccess.Visible = true;
                lblsuccess.Text = "Visit saved";
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                lblsuccess.Visible= false;
             }
```

Comment: Cant get this to work its doesnt display the label, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it by java-script jquery [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function as follows

 **Note that the delay is an integer indicating the number of milliseconds to delay execution of the next item in the queue.**

In `doucment.ready` function of jquery you can write

```
$("#lblsuccess").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
```

or you want to use client id then

```
 $("#<%=lblsuccess.ClientID %>")..delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
```

Comment: Cant really use this as is client side and my code is using server side

Comment: @wubblyjuggly  you need to use client side script other wise you will have refresh the page after 2 seconds.

Comment: Not if you use an UpdatePanel and a script manager to perform asynchronous postbacks.